# When I try to run a command I get the error `The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable'

Tags: bash

when I try to run in the terminal, I get the error `The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable`.

e..g.

```
jeper@jeper:~$ clear
Command 'clear' is available in '/usr/bin/clear'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
clear: command not found
```

and like

```
jeper@jeper:~$ vi
Command 'vi' is available in '/usr/bin/vi'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
vi: command not found
```

What is the issue is and what is the way to resolve it?

Comment: what does /usr/bin/env show?

Comment: open server in Winscp and find folder :/bin/environment in changes

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your $PATH is empty.
Try `echo $PATH`, the output should be similar to this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
```

If not, you should check your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.
Or if you use the `su username` command to switch users, you should use `su - username` next time.

Answer (score 3):

When you issue a command name in the terminal, the system will look for an executable of that name in a list of directories where it is supposed to find such executables. This list is called your *path* and in the bash shell (and most other *nix shells), it is saved in the `$PATH` variable. Since you seem to be using bash, read on.

The `$PATH` is set up in different places. First, there is the system wide `$PATH` which is set up in `/etc/profile`. Every new user inherits the `$PATH` that is set up there. Normally, `/usr/bin` should be added to the system `$PATH` in `/etc/profile`, for example, on my Debian, I have:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
export PATH
```

You then have the various user-specific bash startup files. Which one is read depends on *how* you are launching bash, if it is being run as an interactive or non-interactive shell and if it is a login shell or not. See @Gilles's very good answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/183980/151431) on the different files read by different shell invocations.

To summarize, to add a specific directory to you user's `$PATH` without changing the system-wide settings, add this line to your `$HOME/.profile` file:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

`~/.profile` is read by all shells, not just `bash` and it is read once when you log in. `~/.bashrc` on the other hand, is read every time you open a terminal so that is not where you want to set your `$PATH` since you only need to set it once and don't need to have it reset every time you open a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this

Go to (enter in terminal):

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

click on the .bashrc tab and paste the following in the bottom of the file

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

It'll work just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Terminal (ctrl+alt+T):

1. `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`
2. PASTE at the end of file:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
   ```
3. `ctrl+X` -> `Y` -> `Enter`
4. `source ~/.bashrc`